# Singly-linked list add nodes in the middle

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

```
class List {
  ListNode *head;
  ListNode *prev;
};

class ListNode {
  int data;
  ListNode *next;
  friend class List;
  ListNode(int d, ListNode *n) : data(d), next(NULL) {}
  void insertM(int d) {
    ListNode *ptr, *temp, *curr;
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr->data < d) {
      prev = ptr;
      ptr = ptr->next;
    } // end while
    temp = prev->next;
    curr = new ListNode(d, ptr);
    curr->next = prev->next; // or temp->next
    prev->next = curr;
    ;
  }
};

List mylist;
```

In this function, I'm trying to add a node in the middle of linked list. Other functions add items to the back and front just fine. When I add in the middle of the list, my prev->next links to curr just fine, but curr->next points to NULL.

I have been trying to make this program work for past 1.5 hours. I'll appreciate your help. This is homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general procedure you'll want to use is:

1. surf down the `next` pointers until you reach the node you want to insert after (call it A)
2. change your inserted node (B)'s `next` pointer to match that of A's `next` pointer
3. change A's `next` pointer to point to B

It looks from your code that you're trying to maintain a sorted list of integers. This being homework you probably won't get a code snippet, but from glancing at your code, I have to ask why you take a next parameter in your node constructor, but then set the next value to null. Without seeing the rest of your code I can't say for sure, but I'd change `next(NULL)` on line 9 to be `next(n)`, and then remove the `curr->next` line near the bottom

Comment: Now my code is working. It has been working but then I changed next(n) to next(NULL) for some reason. Now it's working fine. Thank you!